# Process all yield items in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently I have a Scrapy Spider yielding various items on the parse method. Is there any way to get all items that have been yield, regardles of how many times the parse method has been called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pipeline you'll be able to accumulate all items in an array like structure (`process_item` in your pipeline):

```
self.items.append(item) # I use self.items class variable defined at your pipeline
```

and process all of them in `spider_closed`.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about what you mean by get the items. If you want to export them  into a file you can use the [feed export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports), by executing the spider like:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_data.csv
```

*It supports other extensions, check the link for those.*

From your title it seems you want to process the yielded items, in that case you need an [ItemPipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline). From the docs:

> After an item has been scraped by a spider, it is sent to the Item
> Pipeline which processes it through several components that are
> executed sequentially.
>
> ...
>
> Typical uses of item pipelines are:
>
> - cleansing HTML data
> - validating scraped data (checking that the items contain certain fields)
> - checking for duplicates (and dropping them)
> - storing the scraped item in a database

You can also see some pipelines examples [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example).

Both methods operate independently of how many times `parse` method has been called.

Comment: Via pipeline it's possible to get a list with all items and not one by one?

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways to do this.

Firstly, you can simply save the output in the JSON file using command `scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_data.json`. Secondly, you can write a pipeline and store the output in any DB to structure you want.